# getting error - ERROR in app: Exception on /delete [POST], while trying to delete a record from mysql table using python and postman

Tags: python, mysql, api, flask

Here is the python script

```
@app.route("/delete", methods=['POST'])
def delete_record():
 mydb = con.connect(host="localhost", user="root", password="password", database="mysql_python")
 cursor = mydb.cursor()

 first_name = request.json['firstname']
 query = "delete from user_accounts where First_Name = %s"

 try:
     cursor.execute(query, first_name)
     mydb.commit()
     mydb.close()
     return "success"
 except Exception as e:
     return e
```

Here is json script passing from postman

```
{
    "firstname":"Vikrant"
}
```

i am new to postman, trying to test the api through **http://127.0.0.1:5000/delete** using **POST** method. Not getting what i am doing wrong.

Here is full error

```
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
[2022-08-21 11:43:41,281] ERROR in app: Exception on /delete [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abhi\PycharmProjects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\abhi\PycharmProjects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\abhi\PycharmProjects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1842, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\abhi\PycharmProjects\api\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2170, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, list, tuple with headers or status, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a ProgrammingError.
127.0.0.1 - - [21/Aug/2022 11:43:41] "POST /delete HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Error on postman

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang=en>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or
    there is an error in the application.</p>
```

Comment: Are you wanting to send the error as HTML? If so, then cast it to a string first

Comment: @AnthonyL now error on postman changed to `Could not process parameters: str(Vikrant), it must be of type list, tuple or dict`

Comment: Is the status code 200 now?

Comment: @AnthonyL yes, thankyou error has been resolved by passing name in list as `cursor.execute(query, [first_name])` which was earlier `cursor.execute(query, first_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minor change has resolved the error, which was -
parameter need to be pass as list, tuple or dict as the error suggest
so i passed it as

`cursor.execute(query, [first_name])`

which was earlier

```
cursor.execute(query, first_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the error message to any one of the acceptable formats like string or list or tuple or dict and return it.
That will solve your issue.

For permanent solution check your delete cursor and fix it